# How to add wildcard after the root directory in Codeigniter route.php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, routes

How can i directly add wildcard after the root directory like

```
$route['/:any'] ='controller/method';
```

is at possible in Codeigniter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'controller/method';
```

See Codeigniter [manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use (:any) instead of /:any